# How to sort the column in datagrid view ? which events involved in it?

Tags: vb.net, sorting, datagrid

I am developing windows application in vb.net.

I have datagrid with several columns and I want to sort the column which I have selected.

AS you can see in below image , I have selected the ID column and when I click on the Sort Button it should get sort either ascending or Des ceding order.

(Right now Im not worrying about order, I am more interested in the code.)

[image]

I have check several question regarding the sorting issue, but no one answered which events are involved in it, they have given just a code.

Till now , I can only able to write the below code, which selects the column, but this will not work because I have written hard coded 0 column index in the code.

How to write the code of selecting the column and Sorting ?

```
 Private Sub gvBatchList_ColumnHeaderMouseClick(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellMouseEventArgs) Handles gvBatchList.ColumnHeaderMouseClick

        For Each c As DataGridViewColumn In gvBatchList.Columns
            c.SortMode = DataGridViewColumnSortMode.NotSortable
            c.Selected = False
        Next
        gvBatchList.SelectionMode = DataGridViewSelectionMode.FullColumnSelect
        gvBatchList.Columns(0).Selected = True
    End Sub
```

Imp Note : I am using Access Database to store the records and using collection while binding the records to grid view.

The code below shows how I bind the record....

```
 Private Sub LoadAllRegularEmployees()
        Try
            Me.Cursor = Cursors.WaitCursor
            DataGridView1.AutoGenerateColumns = False
            Dim oEmployees As New Employees
            oEmployees.LoadAllRegularEmployees()
            DataGridView1.DataSource = oEmployees
            lblEmployeesCount.Text = "Toal Employees (" + oEmployees.Count().ToString + ")"
            txtEmployeeSearch.Focus()
            Me.Cursor = Cursors.Arrow
        Catch ex As Exception
            Me.Cursor = Cursors.Arrow
            MessageBox.Show("Error :- " + ex.Message.ToString(), "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)

        End Try

    End Sub
```

Comment: Is setting the property of the column's `SortMode` to `Automatic` not an option? Then the user just has to click on the column header to sort.

Comment: this question should be using tag of `datagridview` instead of `datagrid`. the OP should also provide more info, at least what kind of datasource he's using.

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT:**

If at first you don't succeed... and so on.

```
Select Case sortDescending
    Case True
        gvBatchList.Sort(gvBatchList.SelectedColumns(0), ListSortDirection.Ascending)
        sortDescending = False
    Case Else
        gvBatchList.Sort(gvBatchList.SelectedColumns(0), ListSortDirection.Descending)
        sortDescending = True
End Select
```

Here, I defined a boolean `sortDescending`, and used it to check which way we are sorting. I initialized it as `False`, but if you want it to sort Ascending first, you'd just initialize it as `True`.

You will also have to Import `System.ComponentModel` to use `ListSortDirection`.

Hopefully that does it!

---

<s>I think this is what you're asking for:</s>

```
gvBatchList.Sort(gvBatchList.SelectedColumns(0), SortOrder.Ascending)
```

Alternatively, you can use `SortOrder.Descending` to sort in the other direction. Maybe something like this?

```
Select Case gvBatchList.SelectedColumns(0).SortMode
    Case SortOrder.Descending
        gvBatchList.Sort(gvBatchList.SelectedColumns(0), SortOrder.Ascending)
    Case Else
        gvBatchList.Sort(gvBatchList.SelectedColumns(0), SortOrder.Descending)
End Select
```

I can't vouch for what will happen if your user doesn't have a column selected.

Comment: I have tried but It gives an error :- An unhandled exception of type 'System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException' occurred in mscorlib.dll

Additional information: Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection. selecting a column is the main event, how to do that ?

Comment: Before we dive further into this, see my comment on your question. Can we set the `SortMode` of the column to `Automatic`, or are there reasons you can't do that?

Comment: Yes we can set it to aromatic but how to do that ?

Comment: Are you using Visual Studio, or do you need to do it programmatically? EDIT: Either way, there's a catch. You can't have Full Column Select enabled _and_ use the automatic Sort Mode.

Comment: Yes I am using visual Studio. I am quite confused...What exactly I suppose to do ? I am OK with any option...just sorting has to be done...

Comment: If you right click on your DataGridView and click "Edit Columns...", you can set the `SortMode` to `Automatic`. You may have to change the `SelectionMode` Property to something other than FullColumnSelect for everything to work, however. This way, your user doesn't need to click a button to sort - they just need to click on the column header.

Comment: Yes, I got it...I set to automatic....I just checked before biding the record , I can see the upper and lower arrow on the column header, the moment I bind the collection to grid it disappeared.

Comment: Do you have a sub that runs when you bind the collection? If so, it's possible that the SortMode is being changed within that sub.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/98654/discussion-between-user1650894-and-charliefox2).

Answer (score 0):

objSort = objSort.OrderBy(Function(x) x.Assembly).ToArray()